# scipy.optimize error: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I am trying to use scipy.optimize spo, and keep on getting error " 'numpy.float64' object is not callable". Could anyone point me to where the error is coming from? TIA!

[image]

Comment: Please share your code as formatted text, not an image. Also, if you can share the full traceback that would also help

Comment: it's coming from your code!.  You must be using a float (number) where `minimize` expects a function.  But you have the code and full error message; we don't

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `scipy.optimize.minimize` is a call able, and you seem to give it a function value instead. In the OP screenshot, what is `-sharpe_ratio`.
You might be looking for `lambda x, prices_norm : -sharpe_ratio(x, prices_norm)`  or some such.